# Negative search in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to extend my negative search in Mongo.

I'm using this:

```
db.name.find({"name":/^((?!Ford).)/, $exist : true});
```

And that works. That returns all document where the name field doesn't contain word or piece of word "Ford" in this example.

But, some of documents doesn't have key "name" and I also want to get that documents. In above example I want to fetch all documents which don't contains word "Ford" in a name and also documents where key "name" doesn't exist at all.

I tried with `$exist : false` but that doesn't give the results that I expect.

Comment: Way to solve your own issue. I recommend adding your answer as an answer and accepting it.

Comment: When you found the answer yourself, please write an answer to your own question. This is not just allowed on stackoverflow, it is even encouraged to share your knowledge that way.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know about that role.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!

We didn't use `'$or'` operator and that's why it didn't work with `$exists => false`

Here is solution:

```
db.getCollection('name').find({ 
                             $or: [ { "name": { $exists: false } }, 
                                    { "name":/^((?!Ford)}
                                  ]);
```